# Windows / Apache 2.2: Can't reach virtual host by DynDNS due Apache access restrictions

Tags: windows, apache-http-server, dynamic-dns, virtual-host, restrictions

I have configured my Apache 2.2 in Windows as follows:

First deny all access top-down from the top-level-path ...

```
<Directory "/">
  Options None
  AllowOverride All
  Order deny,allow
  Deny from all
</Directory>
```

Second configure the virtual hosts, one for DynDNS allowing access from all and a local one with local IP access restriction only ...

```
Listen *:80
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName dyndnsdomain.example.com
  DocumentRoot "/PathTo/dyndnsdomain/htdocs/"
  <Directory "/PathTo/dyndnsdomain/htdocs/">
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName localdomain
  DocumentRoot "/PathTo/localdomain/htdocs/"
  <Directory "/PathTo/localdomain/htdocs/">
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Third the hosts file ...

```
127.0.0.1 localdomain
```

The problem is I can't reach the DynDNS Domain. DynDNS and port forwarding are configured correctly. My Router sends updates to my DynDNS provider as well. The `Directory` directives are working as expected while removing them restricts the access to the local host.

My questions are:

1. Is my Apache configured correctly?
2. If not what should I change?
   and
3. If yes any suggestions whats going wrong?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "can't reach the DynDNS Domain"? What exactly happens? Please [edit] your question to add more details on the observed behavior, and how this differs from the expected behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is quite hard to tell: Keyword Firewall

2 years ago I decided to restrict Apache from remote access and I totally forgot it because I normally never get in trouble with my settings I made once.

So answering my questions:

1. These Apache settings are correct.
2. n/a
3. Check the firewall settings!